# Upgrading Windows 7 KMS to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I have Windows 7 Enterprise through KMS (Key Management Server, so I get the license from my university). Can I buy the Windows 8.1 upgrade pack from the Microsoft store and upgrade the KMS version? Or will I need to buy the full Windows 8 (i.e. not just the upgrade)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is off topic, although the question has a software theme, at the end of the day it's about licensing. However, if the question is closed, don't be put off  :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment :) No worries if it's closed. Is there another of the stackexchanges where I can ask this question?

Comment: @distraught_user - You are correct. Windows 8.0 is only an upgrade license which means it can only be used to upgrade an existing retail installation of Windows ( Windows XP, Windows Vista, and Windows 7). Microsoft discontinued the "Upgrade" SKU when it released Windows 8.1, which means that if you purchase a Windows 8.1 license, it can only be used to upgrade a retail Windows 7 license to Windows 8.1 ( which does NOT transfer your applications and settings ) only your personal files.  I deleted my comments should I basically repeated what I said in my answer.

Comment: I deleted my comments as well too avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I expected you are running Windows 7 Enterprise which means you will be unable to upgrade to Windows 8.1 Professional.

I will first show the information if you were to first upgrade to a retail version of Windows 8.0.

> ### Upgrade to Windows 8 Pro
>
> You can upgrade to Windows 8 Pro and keep Windows settings, personal
>   files, and applications from the following Windows operating system
>   editions:
>
> •Windows 7 Starter
>
> •Windows 7 Home Basic
>
> •Windows 7 Home Premium
>
> •Windows 7 Professional
>
> •Windows 7 Ultimate

The following information then applies to the retail versions of Windows 8.0 to Windows 8.1

> ### Upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro
>
> You can upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro and keep Windows settings, personal
>   files, and applications from the following Windows operating system
>   editions:
>
> •Windows 8
>
> •Windows 8 Pro
>
> •Windows 8 Pro with Media Center

The following crude table indicates because you are running Windows 7 Enterprise your only upgrade path is Windows 8.X Enterprise.  There are no retail versions of Windows 8.X Enterprise which you can purchase through the Windows Store.  So if you want Windows 8.1 you would have to do a clean installation.

> Can upgrade to Windows RT? -> No
>
> Can upgrade to Windows 8? -> No
>
> Can upgrade to Windows 8 Pro? -> No
>
> Can upgrade to Windows 8 Enterprise? -> Yes

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions)

Tthere are only two versions of Windows 8.1 being sold currently by Microsoft.  `Windows 8.1 "Core"` and `Windows 8.1 Professional` in both cases the license is full license which means it can be used to upgrade Windows 8.0 ( if you decide to do that but a complete waste of money considering its already free for all versions of Windows 8.0) or to upgrade from a retail vesion of Windows 7 where only your personal files are transfered.

If we were talking about a retail version of Windows 7, the advice I would have given, would be to upgrade to Windows 8.0, fully update the product, and install the Windows 8.1 update via the Windows Store.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly the information I needed. Too bad I can't upgrade my Windows 7 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

There are no separate things like buying the upgrade and buying the full version if you are upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1.

So, bottom line is, buy Windows 8.1 or Windows 8.1 Pro and it will work fine without hiccups as far as licensing is concerned.

Rest of the stuff, Ramhound's answer pretty much covers it all.

Comment: Actually won't work because we are dealing with Enterprise to Professional.  If he had Windows 7 Professional it would be an entirely different situation.  As I indicated the Windows 8.1 retail product is a full version, so if he doesn't care about transferring his personal files, applications, and settings he should purchase it.